# Triggering a bootstrap modal on a webpage using a chrome extension content script (without messing up the page CSS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

What's the recommended way to open a bootstrap modal from a content script? I'm aware that CSS and JS files can be injected into a page declaratively via the manifest and programmatically. However, I worry that the injected CSS files (in this case, `bootstrap.min.css`) may conflict with the CSS of the webpage.

What's the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the kind of isolation that you want using a [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM). Shadow DOM basically lets you create an isolated DOM in the context of the existing webpage. All CSS is scoped locally, and the DOM root is considered the root element of the Shadow DOM, as opposed to the true root of the page. You can inject a content script that does the following:

1. Creates a shadow root.
2. Adds a link tag referencing your Bootstrap CSS.
3. Creates the HTML required for a modal and appends it to the shadow root.
4. Opens the modal.

Your content script will still have its regular access to the full window context if you need to get information from the page.

Here's some (completely untested) example code for your content script to illustrate:

```
const shadowWrapper = document.createElement('div');
shadowWrapper.setAttribute('style', `
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`);
const shadowRoot = shadowWrapper.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
const bootstrapStyle = document.createElement('link');
bootstrapStyle.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
bootstrapStyle.setAttribute('src', 'bootstrap.min.css');
shadowRoot.appendChild(bootstrapStyle);

const modal = document.createElement('div');
modal.id = "myModal";
shadowRoot.appendChild(modal);
// Whatever you need to do to create your modal...
$("#myModal").modal();
```

Note that this is only a viable solution if you only want to release this extension on Chrome - Shadow DOM doesn't have great support yet on other browsers (https://caniuse.com/#search=shadow%20dom).

Comment: I am trying to insert the antd Modal but I get the minified react error.